# Does a beeping hard drive signal a professional drive recovery service is required to gain data access?

Tags: hard-drive

My neighbor indicates her Gateway SX2110G Windows 10 returns "[No boot disk has been detected or the disk has failed.](https://appuals.com/fix-no-boot-disk-detected-disk-failed/)"  When connected to a [SATA USB bridge](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075WSPH55): the 3.5" Seagate ST500DM002 drive emits a soft beep and does not spool up.

Comment: You'd have to look at the manual to see what the drive is trying to tell you with the beeping.

Comment: see if you can get SMART stats off the drive. they're a bit more reliable than a beep code, and will help you distinguish hardware failure from soft filesystem damage.

Answer (score 1):

Most modern hard drives do no have any kind of speaker or (intentional) sounds creating devices so a "beep" is likely to be a sign of failure. Many mechanical drives do make gentle noises while spinning up that could be said to sound like a "beep".

It could be that the motor is stuck and while trying to spin up it is vibrating at a frequency sufficient to emit noise in the form of a beep.

It could be that the motor armature is seized up, the bearings are shot, or the head has crashed onto the drive and is stuck holding onto the platters.

While software may confirm that the drive is indeed not spinning up it is unlikely to be able to tell you specifically what the cause might be.

If the drive is crucial and you cannot simply restore from backups then yes you will need to send it to a reputable specialist.